# Oracle Fusion Apps tables and column names - Inventory_Item_ID field

Tags: oracle-fusion-apps

The Inventory_Item_ID field is found in many tables.  However, in out instance I am finding two different kinds of values.  One is a long value like: **100000004710126** and most of the others are short values like: **10331**.  The tables which can also contain the ITEM_NAME contains the short version of the Inventory_Item_ID.  I need to find a table that has both long and short versions of the Inventory_Item_ID so I can complete my joins.

Stated another way, how do I join INV_PHYSICAL_ADJUSTMENTS to MSC_ITEMS?